# How to correctly throw an TypeError when certain parameters are used in a function using Mocha/Chai

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

So, I got this code:

```
function initial(a,b,c){
    if ( isNaN(a) || isNaN(b) || isNaN(c) ){
        //do something
    }
    else {
        //do something
    }  
}
```

I need to expect an *TypeError* when a string is used instead of a number. Initially I thought that declaring expectations for `a`, `b` and `c` separately would be ok, like this:

```
 expect(a).to.be.a('number');
 expect(b).to.be.a('number');
 expect(c).to.be.a('number');
```

I want it to actually observe the function and expect certain parameters to throw an error, something like:

```
expect( initial('foo','foo','foo') ).to.Throw(TypeError);
```

But this is not working, and I've tested quite some options and none seem to actual give me the *TypeError* I want. Does any body know the right way to expect certain function parameters?

Comment: use `throw new TypeError('message');`

Comment: @japrescott I was not actually talking about the TypeError part, but how to expect certain function parameters. Maybe I didn't express myself correctly. Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, having the function:

```
function initial(a, b, c) {
    if ([...arguments].filter(isNaN).length > 0) {
        throw 'Function received a non-number';
    } else {
        return 'ok!';
    }
}
```

you could test its behaviour like this:

```
describe('test my function', function() {
    it('should throw when wrong arguments passed', function() {
        let res, err;
        try {
            res = initial(1, 'a', 3);
        } catch (e) {
            err = e;
        }
        expect(!!res).to.equal(false);
        expect(err).to.equal('Function received a non-number');
    });
    it('should return the expected result', function() {
        let res = initial(1, 2, 3);
        expect(res).to.equal('ok!');
    });
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ywz6djqb/

Comment: cool, it works! but isn't there a way to write it using just one line?

Comment: @PauloGabriel depends on what you want to test, can you describe your needs better?

Comment: I need to test possible errors in my function, like having a 'string' as one of the parameters, or having a 0. I wanted to actually list examples of bad parameters and throw errors, like:

`expect( initial(1,1,'foo') ).to.Throw(TypeError);`
`expect( initial('foo','foo','foo') ).to.Throw(TypeError);`

At some point I've used `expect( function(){initial('foo','foo','foo')} ).to.Throw(TypeError);` but it keeps saying that function initial is not defined.

Comment: @PauloGabriel what happens inside the function when wrong data is passed? should the function `throw`? in that case you need a `try/catch` outside it to test it.

Comment: I did not. I'm even thinking I didn't get files properly set and my test file was not actually reading my main script. I gotta review it some more!

Comment: @PauloGabriel Let me know if I can help more. You can also find me on portuguese Stackoverflow.